# Office 2007 Colours

Tags: microsoft-office-2007

Is there a way to have say Outlook 2007 show in Black, but Excel 2007 show in blue etc?

Comment: Install 1 Office 2007 on your Windows with 1 color, than another Office in a VM with another color (better if you use the Windows Virtual PC mode on Windows 7 so the windows are running on the desktop). Add several virtual XP instances, one for each Office color you want ;-)

Answer (score 6):

I don't believe there is a way to set the Office 2007 color schemes per application.
I think that setting the color is done per the entire Office suite, no matter from which Office application the change was done:

[image]

Comment: I tend to stay with the Blue Theme. The Black Theme looks weird, especially with Outlook.